# Error: Cannot find module './dashboard/dashboard.module' Error: Cannot find module './dashboard/dashboard.module' angular 8

Tags: angular7, angular8

app-routing-module.ts

```
 const routes: Routes = [   {
    path: '',
    component: CmsLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [],
     children: [
       {
         path: '',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
       }
    ]   } ];
```

I have below error show that the  new module added in routing but path not found.

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './dashboard/dashboard.module'
Error: Cannot find module './dashboard/dashboard.module'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3h2A.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the bellow pattern :

```
const routes: Routes = [   {
    path: '',
    component: CmsLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [],
     children: [
        {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      }
    ]   } ];



];
```